# Is this Medium Voltage Distribution Delta or WYE

Tags: power, three-phase, power-engineering

You have been extremely helpful before on a few things. I have another question. This is involves medium voltage 15 kV AC 3 phase distribution 3 conductor plus ground, shielded cable. Braided/twisted together.

The cable configuration in the ground/duct is as follows. Our cable is installed 3 conductor plus ground (I don't believe it's a neutral since its bare, and ties into the shielding of the cables, NOT CONCENTRIC NUETRAL), twisted together. 15 kVAC MV 133% cable.

**Where we have dead breaks, all of the shields are bonded together, to each of the dead break metal brackets, and dead break boots.**

**Where we have dead front sectionalizing/tie switches, the shields are bonded together, to the dead break boots, and to the lug on the switch.**

**At the disconnect switches before transformers, phases are terminated to switch poles, and shields bonded together and to the case of switch, to I "believe" ground/lug.**

My questions:

1. Is this a delta system or a wye. I believe it to be delta correct?
2. If one phase is cut, and breaker does not trip for instance, both ends of that cut cable will be energized correct?
3. If one phase trips or faults out, the other 2 phases are energized and supporting the load lost from the other correct?
4. If this was wye, wouldnt the neutral be insulated fully, and have its own pole at disconnect, tie, sectionalizing switches, and breaker?
5. If it was WYE would there be a "fourth" load break and not just 1 for each phase?
6. The shield tape on MV cable cant be used as a neutral, so it cant be a WYE system?

Any information is extremely appreciated, Im trying to learn more what the other guys dont know about. Also if there are any good books or videos on underground distribution, and cable testing, I would love to hear about them.

Thank you

Comment: I would hope that if your (I assume) company is making you muck around with a 15kV system, they would have *someone* around who is qualified to answer these questions instead of hoping you get the right answer from random strangers on the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately, information is hard to come by. As a separate department from the electricians, and substations, we are basically just installers and do not work energized. And do as engineering says for the most part.

Comment: If you’re doing the engineering, you should know if it’s delta or wye. If not, take a step back and ask for clarification.

Comment: Are you asking what is the configuration of the transformer secondary that is producing the voltage. You say "system" and this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Andy, Correct. We get power from local power company. It goes into our substation. In our 13.2KV distribution, it does not get stepped down and goes right to our grid. In our 4.8KV distribution, we step down the 13.2k to our 4.8K. Then it goes into our ducts through the city to its destination.   I want to know what our end of it is, I believe it would be Delta. As on most of our transformers Ive seen at our destinations the cables are feeding, the are Delta/WYE transformers.

Comment: Winny, we do not do the engineering, we do the install, splicing, and termination. but not to the transformers them selves.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wye transformer windings can be used with 3P-3wire setups, or 3P-4wire setups.  Delta only with 3 wire. Having said that, if you have only 3 wires, delta is most likely.
2. All 3-phase switching and MCBs should be coordinated (all on - all off) to ensure isolation. Only opening one phase will not give you isolation (in the same way that switching neutral in a single phase system, will leave the load side live).
3. If one line fails in a 3 wire three phase system, you only have one phase left.  If you have three phase motors to start, it is entirely possible that the motor will not start and either trip the overload relay or burn up.  You can't assume the other two wires, one phase will "support" the load, as you have lost the rotating element of your supply. You may also find other rectifier base loads misbehave/fail due to insufficient capacitance to carry you over the two lost phases.
4. With 4 wire setups, all the normal choices exist with TT, TN-S, TN-C, PME, PNB, so on entry you may or may not have an insulated neutral, but you should after the main breaker.

However as noted in the comments, don't mess with a MV supply unless you either know the answers to these questions (and others) or the work is being done by someone who does.

Comment: Wouldnt I have 3 Phase 4 wire? being that the cable has 3 phase and the ground thats its braded with? Or you mean connected to the breakers and transformer?

Comment: Also, its my understanding on Delta distribution, if one phase opens, the other two  load balance and take the extra load? Which is another reason for delta distribution and transmission.

Comment: "3 phase 4 wire" is actually 5 wire inside site=3P+N+E whilst "3 phase 3 wire" is 4 wire inside site=3P+E

Comment: No, on one wire failure in 3P+E, you only have one phase left between the two remaining wires.  This is not enought for most motors, or for many rectifier loads

Comment: Delta transmission is attractive as it only needs 3 wires.

Comment: So this is in fact Delta. 3 phase 4 wire is WYE and 3 phase 3 wire is Delta.

Comment: Also, talking the front of Dead front pad mount transformer. if the distribution was in wye, would there be 4 dead breaks made up? 3 phases and the neutral?